# Faster Find and Replace

Tags: replacement, symbolic

I have an expression with 8000 terms all added up. In each term there is `Abs[wm]` which I want to replace by `wm`. If I go to Edit and then Find and then Replace All, it takes FOREVER! I have access to a 16 Core supercomputer. Is there a way I can speed things up by combining it with parallelize, for example?

Comment: `expr /. Abs[wm] -> wm`? (where `expr` is your expression).

Comment: Find and Replace is terribly slow in the front end!

Comment: this is of course completely irrelevant, but I think the times when a 16 core machine would be considered a supercomputer are long gone :-)

Comment: I don't know if you are still following this, but I just wanted to make sure you understand that what march, M.R. and Alexey are all suggesting is to switch from a slow implemention of an effective string search&replace to the core and most powerful part of Mathematica: its symbolic pattern matcher. If what I wrote seems to not make sense to you I'd suggest to stop with what you are doing, accepts Alexeys answer and then invest a week or two in learning the basics of computer algebra systems and the Mathematica pattern matcher :-)...

Answer (score 4):

One simple way is:

```
expr /. Abs -> Identity
```

where `expr` is your expression.

This method will replace all the `Abs[x]` with `x` (where `x` is arbitrary expression) on the all levels. If the latter isn't desirable and you wish to replace only the topmost appearances of `Abs`, the following method is preferred:

```
expr /. Abs[x_] :> x
```

If you wish to replace only explicit instances of `Abs[wm]`, then the method suggested in comments should be used:

```
expr /. Abs[wm] -> wm
```

Comment: Not bad but suppose there are other `Abs[]` subexpressions that are not meant for replacing?

Comment: @Daniel I extended the answer to address this (for simplest cases).

Comment: Thanks to all for educating me. It was very helpful.